# Native SQL Server connection vs ODBC?

Tags: sql-server, odbc

What is the difference between native SQL Server connection and ODBC? What are the benefits when using native SQL Server connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When possible, you should always use Sql Native Client, or the Native Sql Data Provider. It is far more superior in terms of performance than an ODBC connection.

ODBC is basically another layer of abstraction. It might be interesting if you want to support different databases and to switch them at run-time, but if you're sure you're going to stick with Sql Server, Native Client is the way to go.

Comment: Is the performance only thing you should consider when deciding which connection method to use?

Comment: @jrara: No, you should first consider if you need the extra abstraction layer, so if you need to be able to easily switch databases later. If that is not the case, there's no point in using ODBC.